# How to use the data that you get from a Discrete Wavelet Transform pwyt?

Tags: regression, time-series, wavelet, transform

Im using the pywt (PyWavelets) python library to remove the Gaussian Noise from a timeseries dataset.

b is a python list of timeseries values like this, [33.33, 34.23, 35.65...]

(cA, cD) = pywt.dwt(b, 'db1')

how can I use cA and cD in a regression algorithm to make a prediction on the future values? do I just remove the approximation coefficient and use the other result because that is the result without the Gaussian Noise?

Can somebody please explain to me what this means?

Answer (score 1):

The detail coefficients, cD, are the terms with the higher frequency components that are more likely to be considered noise. One thing you didn't mention is that there are multiple levels of the decomposition, each separating the detail (cD) from the approximation (cA) at a certain scale. So you'll have to choose a level of granularity to go down to and then work with that scale's cA. Your new time series will have a different length than the original, and you'll have to map it back to the original scale (which may or many not be exactly a factor of 2 depending on the wavelet). There's no inherent link to a regression model so you're starting from scratch with the de-noised series. Hopefully the wavelet you chose didn't add any weird artifacts.

Wavelets are a cool idea and I know they're useful in compression algorithms, but for smoothing and forecasting I would suggest other more accessible methods, like [Simple Exponential Smoothing.](https://robjhyndman.com/talks/RevolutionR/5-ExponentialSmoothing.pdf)

Comment: How do I map it back to the original scale? Wont that destroy the data points of cA?

Comment: If originally you had 512 data points, and your cA only has 128, then you could just repeat each point in cA 4 times, or use the time index associated with {i*4, i = 1,...,128}. More complex wavelets than Haar will often have end effects though, so instead of 128, you might have a length 132, which makes things awkward.

Comment: If you do it this way you might instead want to use `pywt.wavedec()`, which is the multilevel decomposition version of `pywt.dwt()` and gives you the detail coefficients from all levels it computes.

Comment: @BenOgorek mapping back to original scale is done by the inverse transform.

Comment: @BenOgorek you can choose a type of convolution where that does not happen. For example circular or mirrored edges or boundary extension.